# Cost of doing a LEFT JOIN in MySQL vs caching the data

Tags: mysql, caching, redis

so I have this project with the following MySQL tables :

**The content table**

```
+------------+------------+
| content_id | some infos |
+------------+------------+
|          1 | ...        |
|          2 | ...        |
+------------+------------+
```

**The title table**

```
+----+----------+---------+------------+--------------+
| id |  title   | user_id | content_id | other things |
+----+----------+---------+------------+--------------+
|  1 | "blabla" |       1 |          1 | ...          |
|  2 | "blabla" |      59 |         25 | ...          |
+----+----------+---------+------------+--------------+
```

To resume quickly the system, multiple users give a title to a content. But everytime I SELECT a content, I need to find the appropriate title (I take the most followed user witch has posted a title to this content).

So, in order to do that I see 2 solutions :

- I can do a SELECT on the **content** table with a LEFT JOIN on the **title** table and my **user** table with some MAX (nb_subscribers) ...
- I can do a SELECT only on the **content**, and then use a cache system like Redis to cache the title for something like 1 day (in this case, it would require a new MySQL call if a title is not found)

The main problem is that these contents will be loaded a very big number of times, and i'd like to know your adivise if the LEFT JOIN method would need a lot of time to process.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with doing a `LEFT JOIN` between the `content` and `title` table assuming that the latter has an index on the `content_id` column:

```
SELECT c.*, t.*
FROM content c
LEFT JOIN title t
    ON c.content_id = t.content_id
-- can also join to user table if needed
```